# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP for a single file in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to let an external software collect a zip file from my Wordpress site. The site is converted to https, but the software asks for the HTTP version of the file, http://www.example.com/foldername/grunfil.zip

So can I add something in .htaccess to make that file only http?

Here is my current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried this, but it creates an endless loop:

```
redirect 301 /foldername/grunfil.zip http://www.example.com/foldername/grunfil.zip
```

Comment: If you have any HTTP to HTTPS redirect set up elsewhere (hosting panel maybe), then you would need to add an exception for this particular URL there as well, of course. (If that is even possible on that level; otherwise, you would have to disable that redirect there, and completely handle it yourself via the .htaccess.)

Comment: Do you mean that the redirect 301 I tried should work then?
The https for the is setup with a free certificate in directadmin. I have no idea on how to make an exception there.

Comment: No, that redirect will not work then either - because it doesn’t check if the request was not made using HTTPS already, so it will create an endless loop then.

Comment: Or I can disable the certificate in directadmin and only handle it in .htaccess?

Comment: You can not handle the SSL setup itself in .htaccess. You need to go and figure out whether you can disable the automatic redirect on its own in your current setup.

Comment: To me this reads as if you do not want a redirect at all. If that software _really_ insists on fetching the object via http (there is no such thing as a "http version of a file", files/Objects and protocol are completely separate things), then it won't make an https request, so there is nothing to redirect. Instead you have to make sure that your http host answers to http at all and you need to implement an exception to your http to https redirection if you have such.

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule, maybe it help.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^foldername\/grunfil\.zip
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. It still doesn't work when I used Jarekbarans solution.
The software is giving me a message: "Cannot create SSL/TLS secure channel".